# Why does operator = return *this?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, copy-assignment

Say I want to override the `operator =` so I can do something like

```
Poly p1;  // an object representing a polynomial
Poly p2;  // another object of the same type    
p2 = p1;  // assigns all the contents of p1 to p2
```

Then in my implementation of the `operator =`, I have something like this:

```
Poly& Poly::operator=(const Poly &source) {
    // Skipping implementation, it already works fine…
    return *this;
}
```

Don't mind the implementation, it already works fine.

My concern is that what happens when you `return *this`? I know it returns a reference to the object but is this what happens?

```
p2 = &p1
```

Comment: Since the `I am just new to C++` part has been lost in an (otherwise well meant) edit, and since variations of `p2 = &p1` resurfaced in the comments... The `&` in the `Poly&  Poly::operator=` declaration means that the operator returns a reference - to itself in this case, which is precisely what `return *this;` does. On the other hand, the `&` in `&p1` evaluates to the address of `p1`, which is a `Poly*` pointer, and cannot be assigned to a `Poly` object. Do not confuse the two meanings of `&` in the two different contexts.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You `return *this` so you can write normal compound C++ `=` statements like:

```
Poly p1; //an object representing a polynomial
Poly p2;
Poly p2;

// ...

p3 = p2 = p1;  //assigns all the contents of p1 to p2 and then to p3
```

because that statement is basically:

```
p3.operator=(p2.operator=(p1));
```

If `p2.operator=(...)` didn't `return *this` you'd have nothing meaningful to pass into `p3.operator=(...)`.

Comment: yes I know that. But my concern is what happens when you return *this? I mean, basing from your example, does it work like this?

p3 = p2 = &p1;
p3 = &p2;

Comment: @JudeMaranga Edited answer accordingly.  You don't want to take the address of, say `p1` (*i.e.* `&p1`), `operator=` takes a `const Poly &source` so `*this` gives you that.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say in there. but after p3.operator=(...) return *this, who would be catching that return value?

Comment: @JudeMaranga It just the same as `42;` being a valid C++ statement.  The value is thrown away.  Think about `cout << "C++ throws unused "  << "return values away" << endl`;

Comment: Nothing is catching the `p3` return, but that's fine.  Paul's explanation is correct.  No worse than `(void) sqrt(9.0)` [useless, but legal].

Comment: @CraigEstey so sir, if I don't want to have nested assignments, would it just be fine if I make the return value of my operator = as void?

Comment: @JudeMaranga The technique might be more familiar to you in constructs like `thing.doSomething().with(thisThing).andAlso(thatThing).fast().andNot().slow()` which is a more awkward syntax for basically the same thing.

Comment: @JudeMaranga That's only reason for the `return *this`.  So yes, you don't need if **you're never going to use nested assignment**.  But it's a convention and best stuck to.  If you don't you know you're going to get bitten at some point in the future.

Comment: @PaulEvans Maybe you can answer [better] Jude's question to me.  But, I'd say, that you're only talking about a single extra `mov xxx,%eax` (e.g.) and I think you also have to conform to what the `=` operator requires.  AFAIK, you don't get to choose an alternate [incompatible] return type.  You can't predict the calling context.  Just relax and do the return :-)

Comment: @PaulEvans I actually disagree that this is the *only reason*. Another application is directly using the result of an assignment as is frequently done in the condition of an `if` or `while` statement.

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes, that's correct.  But surely we don't write assignments in boolean expressions.  `if ( x = y ...` being very bad form.

Comment: How about [the equally montrous equivalent]: `if ((f = fopen(...)) != NULL)`? [I _never_ do that, but it's ubiquitous]

Comment: I think that `while (p = p.derivative()) { … }` would be very reasonable code (assuming the conversion operator to `bool` returns `true` for any non-null polynomial). You can add an extra layer of parenthesis if you prefer.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes, there's load of &%$! that's ubiquitous.  Doesn't mean we can't do better :) )

Comment: @5gon12eder Hmmm, I'd rather avoid the possibility that the `=` is mistaken for `==` (or even *changed* to `==` in a later edit!)).  But I see your point, `while` loops can be tricky to get right without too much noise.

Comment: You could put a comment `// single = is intentional here`

Answer (score 10):

`p2 = p1` is a shorthand for `p2.operator=(p1)`.  It is just calling your `operator=` function, which is returning a reference to `p2`, which you are then ignoring.  To make this clear, let's call it `assign` instead of `operator=`:

```
Poly& Poly::assign(const Poly &source) {
    .
    .
    .
    return *this;
}
```

Now instead of `p2 = p1`, you would write

```
p2.assign(p1);
```

In this case, the result of calling `assign` is being ignored, but you don't have to ignore it. For example, you could write:

```
p3.assign(p2.assign(p1));
```

Using `operator=` instead of `assign`, this becomes

```
p3 = (p2 = p1);
```

but since assignment is right-associative, this can also be written as

```
p3 = p2 = p1;
```

This form of being able to do multiple assignments at once originally comes from C and has been preserved in C++ through the convention of returning `*this` in `operator=()`.

Comment: the returned reference is just ignored? So why not make it void if the return value would just be ignored anyway?

Comment: @JudeMaranga: I've extended my answer to help explain.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I made a small edit.  Thanks for letting me know what happened.

Comment: @VaughnCato and why not returning a const reference, instead? Isn't it safer?

Answer (score 7):

One might be tempted to make the copy-assignment operator return `void` if you won't ever need chained assignments (as shown in the other answers) anyway. After all, chained assignments are often hard to read and understand, so not allowing them might be considered an *improvement*.

However, an often overlooked aspect is that `void operator=(Poly& const)` means that your type would no longer fulfuill the [**`CopyAssignable` concept**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable), which requires a `T&` return type.

A type which does not fulfill the `CopyAssignable` concept cannot be officially used for some standard-container operations, for example `std::vector::insert`, which means that the following seemingly innocent piece of code yields undefined behaviour, even though it probably runs perfectly fine:

```
#include <vector>

struct Poly
{
    void operator=(Poly const&) {} // Poly is not CopyAssignable
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Poly> v;
  Poly p;
  v.insert(v.begin(), p); // undefined behaviour
}
```

As the C++ standard explains in § 17.6.4.8/2.3 where it talks about constraints on programs using the standard library:

> (...) the effects are **undefined** in the following cases:
>
> (...) for types used as template arguments when instantiating a
> template component, **if the operations on the type do not implement the
> semantics of the applicable Requirements** subclause (...).

Of course, it's precisely *because* of the undefined behaviour that a compiler is allowed to ignore the error and make the program behave nicely, matching the obviously intended behaviour. But it's not required to do so.

You should also consider that you cannot predict all future uses of your `Poly` type. Someone might write some template function such as:

```
template <class T>
void f(T const& t)
{
    T t2;
    T t3 = t2 = t;
    // ...
}
```

This function would then not work with your `Poly` class.

Just don't violate this C++ convention and you won't run into troubles.

Answer (score 3):

> what happens when you return *this?

In your example (`p2 = p1;`), nothing.  The method copies `p1` into `p2` and returns a reference to the 'this' object, which the calling code doesn't use.

In code such as `p3 = p2 = p1;`, the first invocation is `p2 = p1`, which copies `p1` into `p2` and returns a reference to `p2`.  The calling code then copies from that reference-to-`p2` into `p3` (and ignores the reference to `p3` that is returned).

(In passing: do your unit tests ensure that `p1 = p1` works properly?  It's easy to forget that case!)

Comment: If you implement the operator correctly, using the copy-and-swap idiom, then you don't need to handle self-assignment at all. Indeed, `if (this != &other)` is often an indicator of dangerous code. An exception may be made for rare optimisation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a reference to the target object allow assignment chaining (cascading), and overloading operators within a class follows right-associative (click [here](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) for detailed operator overloading rules)

```
Poly a, b, c;
a = b = c;
```