# Ampersand and dereferencing `this` when overloading operators in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading, this

I think I am missing something obvious but I can't see what.

I am starting to create classes which require operator overloading. I don't understand one convention I am reading for overloading them: in the code below I am taking as an example the operator `+=`. Now, in this example the operator overload is declared as **a reference to an object** of the class, but then the return statement **de-references** the pointer to the current object, so it should be returning its value (right?). To me this looks like a contradiction. I would actually expect the `return` statement to return an address, not a value.

```c++
NewClass& NewClass::operator+=(...){
   //some code here
   return *this;
}
```

I have see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562865/why-does-operator-return-this) regarding returning `*this` and I understand the logic there, but that does not answer my lack of understanding on what I see as a contradiction between declaring a reference return and returning what seems a value.

**How to properly interpret this code?**

Comment: The function simply returns a reference to the object you return (the object itself in this case).

Comment: The "value" of an object is not a concrete language concept. The value of an object is the meaning we associate with it. As far as the language is concerned, a value is just an object state. References refer to objects. `*this` produces the object the pointer `this` designates.

Comment: The `&` has many meanings in C++.  The `type&` is a reference to that type.  The `&var` is the address of that var variable.  And `u1 & u2` (assuming u1 and u2 are suitable primitive types) is a bit-wise AND operator.  Confusing?  Yes, somewhat.  You (and the compiler) have to be context aware.  ASCII just didn't have enough operators at the time of C++'s inception.

Comment: references are not pointers.